# Have I found all the numbers less than 50,000 with exactly 11 divisors?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, factoring, divisor-counting-function

The math problem I am trying to solve is to find all positive integers that meet these two conditions:

- have exactly 11 divisors
- are less than 50,000

My starting point is a number with exactly 11 divisors is of the form:

$c_1p_1 * c_2p_2 * c_3p_3 * ... * c_{11}p_{11}$

where:  $c_i$ is an integer and $p_i$ is prime

and noting that 1 can be a divisor but can only be included once in the list of divisors.

Therefore the smallest such number is: $1*2^{10} = 1024$

The next such number would be: $2^{11} = 2048$

So far $c_i$ has been 1, but I will now start letting some of them be 2 until I reach the upper bound of 50,000. This gives me:

$2^{12}$, $2^{13}$, $2^{14}$ and $2^{15}$ (as $2^{16} > 50,000)$

I feel like I'm onto a useful pattern. So I will start using 3s as well (again until I reach the upper bound):

$3*2^{10}$, $3^2*2^9$, $3^3*2^8$, $3^4*2^7$, $3^5*2^6$, $3^6*2^5$, $3^7*2^4$

Now 4s: $4*2^{10}$, $4^2*2^9$, $4^3*2^8$, $4^4*2^7$

Then 5s: $5*2^{10}$, $5^2*2^9$, $5^3*2^8$

Then 6s: $6*2^{10}$, $6^2*2^9$

Then 7s: $7*2^{10}$, $7^2*2^9$

Then 8s: $8*2^{10}$, $8^2*2^9$

Then 9s: $9*2^{10}$, $9^2*2^9$

Then 10s: $10*2^{10}$

I've now reached the point where there's only one number in the sub-sequence. Therefore, I also have:

$11*2^{10}, 12*2^{10}, 13*2^{10}, ..., 48*2^{10}$

I now feel I've exhausted my algorithm. However I'm not sure if my answer is correct and complete. So, have I enumerated all such numbers? Or have I missed some or doubled-up?

Comment: $2^{11}$ has $12$ divisors.

Comment: @DougM Do I have to include 1? I was thinking 2 * 2 * 2 * ... * 2 is 11 distinct divisors.

Comment: @dave: The divisors of 2048 are {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048}. Count them -- there are twelve of them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh crap, I see my problem. I've confused _divisors_ with _factors_.

Comment: @dave In most cases I am aware of, "divisor" and "factor" are synonyms. In particular, $1$ is both a divisor and a factor of every number.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: But a "number with 11 divisors" is not the same as a "product of 11 factors". It appears that the OP was confused between a number that can be produced by multiplying 11 different numbers together and a number such that eleven different number divides it, _where each divisor is tested separately_.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro thanks for your comment. Speaking as the OP, HenningMakholm's last comment nails it and perfectly describes my confusion.

Comment: In $c_1pi*.....c_{11}p_{11} $ all the c1 are *also* factors so that number has many many more factors than 11.  Not to mention $p_i*p_j $ is yet another factor. Without the $c_i $ and just the $p_i $s the number $p_1p_2....p_{11} $ has factor 1, the 11 $p_i $, the 55 $p_ip_j $ pairs, the 120 $p_ip_jp_k $ triplets, 210 $p_ip_jp_kp_l $ quadruples and so on.  It has over a *thousand* factors!

Comment: The better way is to find out how many factors an arbitrary number has. Take $c=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}... $ how many factors does it have? Take $c=28=2^2*7$ it has $1, 2, 2^2,7,7*2,7*2^2$ or 6 factors. Can you see any relation between the prime factorization and the number 6. Try figuring out how many factors $c=2^53^65^2$ has? Hint it's 126. Second hint: 126=6 x 7 x 3.

Comment: Once you figure out the formula for how many factors a number with a certain prime factorization can have, you can figure that to have 11 factors it must have a certain type of prime factorization.  Hint 11 is prime will *really* narrow it down.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're looking at a number with prime factorization
$$ p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_n^{a_n} $$
(note, there are no $c$s in a prime factorization), then it has exactly $(a_1+1)\cdot(a_2+1)\cdots(a_n+1)$ divisors.

Since $11$ is prime, the only way it can be written as such a product is just $(10+1)$. So you're looking for numbers of the form $p^{10}$ -- **and only that form** -- less than $50,000$.

Comment: And since $(50,000)^{\frac{1}{10}} \approx 2.950 \implies p = 2$ and $n=1024$

Answer (score 13):

If $n$ has a prime factorization of $p_1^ip_2^jp_3^k$, it has $(i+1)(j+1)(k+1)$ divisors.
The numbers with exactly 11 divisors are of the form $p^{10}$ since 11 is prime.

Since $3^{10} > 50,000$, the only answer is $1024$.

Comment: But if you want a number with eleven divisors _smaller than itself_, that could be $p^{11}$ or $p^5q$ or $p^2qr$ or $p^2q^3$, where $p,q,r$ are all prime.

Answer (score 7):

To flog a horse consider how many factors $p^k $ have.  The factors are:

$1,p,p^2,p^3,.......,p^k$

That's $k+1$ factors.

How many factors does $p^kq^m$ have?

$1,p^2,p^3,......,p^k$

$q,qp,qp^2,qp^3,......,qp^k $

$q^2,q^2p,q^2p^2,q^2p^3......,q^2p^k$

......

......

$q^m,q^mp,q^mp^2,q^mp^3.....,q^mp^k$

That is $(k+1)(m+1)$ total factors.

Now how many factors does $\prod p_i^{k_i} $ have?

Well, each $p_i$ prime has factors for every power from 0 to $k_i $.  That's $k_i +1$ factors.  The each of those factors can be multiplied by the powers of any other {1,$p_j,p_j^2,...p_j^{k_j} $.  The total number of combinations is therefore. $\prod (k_i +1) $.

So if $c = \prod p_i^{k_i} $ then $c $ has $\prod (k_i+1) =11$ factors.  as 11 is prime, 11 = $k+1$ so $c=p^{10}$ for some prime $p $.

The only such number in range is $c=2^{10}=1024$ that has 11 factors: 1,2, 4 ,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach doesn't really make sense to me, especially the starting point: Without knowing the form of the $c_i$, how can you assert that your number has $11$ divisors? It actually can't: A number divisible by $11$ distinct primes has $2^{10} = 1024$ distinct divisors.

---

An approach: Factor $N = p_1^{\alpha_1} ... p_k^{\alpha_k}$ with $p_i$ prime and $\alpha_i$ integers that are at least $1$. The number of divisors of $N$ is then
$$(\alpha_1 + 1)(\alpha_2 + 1) \cdots (\alpha_k + 1)$$

In particular, as soon as there are two such terms, this is composite - and not $11$. What can you conclude?

> The number is $p^{10}$ for a prime $p < \sqrt[10]{50000} < 3$.